# Display all tags with specific id with CSS and HTML

Tags: css, html

How do I toggle all HTML tags specific ID using only HTML/CSS?

Example:
HTML:

```
<html>...
<a href="#select">Select</a>
<img src="file.png" id="select">
<p id="select"> Paragraph </p>
...</html>
```

CSS:

```
#select {display: none;}
#select:target {display: block;}
```

I have tried using `<div>` however, when I do, only the some of the tags toggle.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Duplicate IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML**. Try another method.

Comment: Two HTML elements with the same ID attribute values is not valid in HTML. If you absolutely need to use same value try putting it in "name" attribute. Name attribute can take same value for multiple HTML elements. If you need to use same selector in css try using class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you should use a class:

```
<html>...
<a href="#select">Select</a>
<img src="file.png" class="select">
<p class="select" id="select"> Paragraph </p>
.. <html>
```

and the CSS:

```
.select {display: none;}
.select:target {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because duplicate IDs are invalid HTML, you could use a class:

```css
.select { display: none; }
.select:target { display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
<a href="#select">Select</a>
<img src="file.png" class="select">
<p id="select" class="select"> Paragraph </p>

</html>
```